# Typescript function definition: return nested object with keys looked-up from value array

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, signature, .d.ts

I have a method that takes as an input an object whose values are arrays of strings; it returns an object whose values are objects with keys equal to the string values. E.g.

```js
myFunction({foo: ['a', 'b']}) // ==> {foo: {a: Widget, b: Widget}}
```

I'm trying to define the signature of this function. My best attempt is:

```
declare function myFunction
  <Q extends string[], T extends {[key: string]: Q}>
  (keys: T) : {[key1 in keyof T]: {[key2 in T[key1][number]]: Widget}}
```

This *almost* works, except the key names of the nested objects are not inferred. The first example returns:

```
{
    foo: {
        [x: string]: Widget;
    };
}
```

whereas I want it to return

```
{
    foo: {
        a: Widget;
        b: Widget;
    };
}
```

Can that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow TS to fix the inference we need to add additionaly generic type for array keys members:

```
declare function myFunction
  <Q extends K[], T extends {[key: string]: Q}, K extends string>
  (keys: T): { [key1 in keyof T]: { [key2 in T[key1][number]]: Widget } }
```

Pay attention at `Q extends K[]`, we now are saying that `Q` is not `string[]` but `K[]`, it means TS will narrow members of array to more specific types then string.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is always contains only `"a"` and `"b"`, then you can define union type of string literals:

```js
type MyUnionType = "a" | "b"
```

Then define variable `foo` as `MyUnionType[]`. The result is:

```js
declare function myFunction
  <Q extends MyUnionType[], T extends {[key: string]: Q}>
  (keys: T) : {[key1 in keyof T]: {[key2 in MyUnionType]: Widget}}
```

Should work :)

---

But if your array is always consists of different strings, then it's impossible to implement such typing, because TypeScript is only design-time tool

Comment: In general, dynamic key inference does work. E.g. a simpler, non-nested version of the signature behaves as expected:

```javascript
declare function myFunc<T extends string[]>(keys: T) :
  {[key in T[number]]: Widget};

myFunc(['a', 'b']) //==> {a: Widget, b: Widget}
```